# Fast convergence of a contagion process in special graphs

Tags: reference-request, randomness, pr.probability, markov-chains

**The process:** Given is a clique $C_n$ of size $n$. Consider the following synchronous process, also known as the (synchronous) voter model (e.g., [Even-Dar and Shapira](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~asafico/diffusion.pdf)):
Define an indicator variable $x_i(t)$, which denotes the state of node $i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ at step $t$. We interpret $x_i(t)=1$ as "node $i$ is black (infected) at step $t$, and white (uninfected) otherwise."

Initially, $x_1(0)=1$, whereas $x_i(0)=0$ for all $i=2,\ldots,n$. At step $t>0$, each node $i$ picks a neighbour $j \in N(i)$ uniformly at random (we assume that $i \in N(i)$), and sets $x_i(t)=x_j(t-1)$. The process stops only when the nodes are either all-black or all-white. This process is Markovian.

**My problem:** I want to compute the following probability. For a given $t^*$, compute the probability that for every $i=1,\ldots,n$, $x_i(t^*)=0$. Specifically, I want to show that for $t^*=O(\log n)$, the above probability is $1-o(1)$. In words, I want to show that only after a logarithmic number of steps, the entire clique is all-white w.h.p.

This seems to be similar to the extinction problem in branching programs ([wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_process)), but I'm not sure if the results for that problem carry over directly to mine.

**Update:** One can try to solve this problem "from scratch" (without using 
any known related results), by looking at the following measure.

Let $d(t,j)$ denote the probability that the graph is all-white by step $t$, assuming that there are initially $j$ black nodes (e.g., $x_i(0)=1$ for $i=1,\ldots,j$, and $x_i(0)=0$ for $i=j+1,\ldots,n$). Clearly, we are interested in the value of $d(log n, 1)$. Also, 
we have that $d(0,0)=1$ and $d(0,j)=0$ for $j>0$; and also $d(t,0)=1$ for $t \geq 0$.

For $t, j>0$, the recurrence can be expressed as follows:

$d(t,j)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{i}\big(\frac{j}{n}\big)^i\big(\frac{n-j}{n}\big)^{n-i}d(t-1,i)$

But I'm not sure how to solve it.